# QDataStream on QByteArray: Is it safe to read from the array ('[ ]') between writes on the DataStream ('<<')?

Tags: c++, qt, serialization

I'm using a `QDataStream` to serialize data (using the stream's `<<` operator) to a `QByteArray`. But I've been wondering: is it safe to read from the underlying `QByteArray` between `<<` operations (or might I run into e.g. a buffering issue)?

```
quint8 sumBytes(const QByteArray& byteArray)
{
    //This will overflow quickly...
    quint8 result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.size(); i++)
        result += static_cast<quint8>(byteArray[i]);
    return result;
}

QByteArrary createByteArray(qint32 foo, qint32 bar)
{
    QByteArray array;
    QDataStream stream(&array, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    stream<< foo;
    stream<< bar;
    // Safe to access array below?
    const quint8 byteSum = sumBytes(array);
    stream<< byteSum;
    return array;
}
```

I've checked the documentation for `QDataStream` and `QByteArray` but saw nothing relevant, except a mention that `QDataStream` uses a `QBuffer` as `QByteArray` is not a `QIoDevice` (which caused me to ask this question). Yet again, `QDataStream` provides no `flush()` (or similar method), so it might be safe...?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Keep in mind that you've passed a `const` version of your `QByteArray` into `sumBytes`, which guarantees that the internal state of the object won't be changed.

You could also consider using [`.at()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#at):

> `at()` can be faster than `operator[]()`, because it never causes a deep copy to occur.

<sup>[*(source)*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#details)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding the `at()` operator (though I assume the array being a `const &` will here prevent the call of the non-const version of `[ ]` and thus the deep copy). What I am worried about is that the `QDataStream` might have buffered (i.e. not yet committed) the changes / writing to the `QByteArray` causing me to read stale data.

Comment: Ah, I probably misread the question. Interestingly, [QDataStream provides read transactions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#using-read-transactions); not too sure about write transactions though, which I'm guessing are what you're after. 